# Can't make use of dont_filter=true within a spider in the right way to avoid some unwanted activity

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a spider to parse the link from different container from some identical site's (supplied by text file) landing page and then use the link to get the title from it's inner page. Few links have next page button which the spider handles accordingly.

The spider does parse the content but falls into an infinite loop caused by the `dont_filter=True` parameter. If I don't use that parameter, the spider doesn't reuse some links that were failed to produce desired response in the first place.

I've used this parameter `dont_filter=True` in three places.

1. In `_retry()` method within middlewares
2. In the last line within the `parse()` method
3. In the last line within the `parse_content()` method

spider that I've created:

```
import os
import scrapy
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class YelpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yelpspidescript"

    with open("all_urls.txt") as f:
        start_urls = f.readlines()
   
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse,meta={"lead_link":url})

    def parse(self,response):
        if response.meta.get("lead_link"):
            lead_link = response.meta.get("lead_link")
        elif response.meta.get("redirect_urls"):
            lead_link = response.meta.get("redirect_urls")[0]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        if soup.select("[class*='hoverable'] h4 a[href^='/biz/'][name]"):
            for item in soup.select("[class*='hoverable'] h4 a[href^='/biz/'][name]"):
                lead_link = response.urljoin(item.get("href"))
                yield scrapy.Request(lead_link,meta={"lead_link":lead_link},callback=self.parse_content)

            next_page = soup.select_one("a[class*='next-link'][href^='/search?']")
            if next_page:
                link = response.urljoin(next_page.get("href"))
                yield scrapy.Request(link,meta={"lead_link":link},callback=self.parse)

        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(lead_link,meta={"lead_link":lead_link},callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
            
    def parse_content(self,response):
        if response.meta.get("lead_link"):
            lead_link = response.meta.get("lead_link")
        elif response.meta.get("redirect_urls"):
            lead_link = response.meta.get("redirect_urls")[0]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

        if soup.select_one("h1[class*='heading--inline__']"):
            try:
                name = soup.select_one("h1[class*='heading--inline__']").get_text(strip=True)
            except AttributeError: name = ""
            print(name)

        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(lead_link,meta={"lead_link":lead_link},callback=self.parse_content,dont_filter=True)
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
        'LOG_LEVEL':'ERROR',
    })
    c.crawl(YelpSpider)
    c.start()
```

middlewares:

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504, 408, 403, 401, 400, 404, 408]

class yelp_custom_Middleware(object):
    ua = UserAgent() 

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.ua.random

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        return self._retry(request, exception, spider)

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        retryreq = request.copy()
        retryreq.dont_filter = True
        return retryreq

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if request.meta.get('dont_retry', False):
            return response
        if response.status in RETRY_HTTP_CODES:
            reason = response_status_message(response.status)
            return self._retry(request, reason, spider) or response
        return response
```

***How can I let the spider not to fall into an infinite loop?***

EDIT:
I thought to include ***[few of the urls](https://filebin.net/rt5etclsyv59phcn)*** I'm trying with which are within `all_urls.txt` file in case it helps identify the issue better.

Comment: What about adding retry counter?

Comment: If I comply with your suggestion, how will the modified version of  `_retry( )` method look like @gangabass? Thanks.

Comment: @robots.txt can you better explain how the infinite loop happens? I'm asking because even though the filter is "off" it shouldn't enter the loop. The only cases where I've seen it happening is when while parsing the page the spider finds and yields a request to that same page OR when the server keeps you in a infinite redirect loop. **Another question: Is the problem exclusive of the requests yielded by `start_requests` (from the url list) or it also happens along the requests yielded by parsing pages?**

Comment: Answer to your second question: happens to any random url no matter whether they are among the start urls or they are populated by different methods @renatodvc. To your first question: I didn't notice any redirection but I did notice captcha url which the script bypasses using proxies. However, the bottom line is I wish not to let the script fall into an infinite loop. Thanks.

Comment: This becomes considerably more challenging to solve due to not knowing the reason the loop happens, as this is an anomaly by itself. Do you consider a system that limits the amount of requests made to a single URL a reasonable solution?

Comment: Yep, I do @renatodvc and that is the reason I tried with the solution below but I can't handle the `if block` which ends up causing an error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count retries per URL:

```
class yelp_custom_Middleware(object):
    ua = UserAgent()
    max_retries = 3
    retry_urls = {}

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = self.ua.random

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        return self._retry(request, exception, spider)

    def _retry(self, request, reason, spider):
        retry_url = request.url
        if retry_url not in self.retry_urls:
            self.retry_urls[retry_url] = 1
        else:
            self.retry_urls[retry_url] += 1
        
        if self.retry_urls[retry_url] > self.max_retries:
            # Dont' retry
        else:
            # Retry
```

Comment: As soon as I run the script, I get this error `retry_url = request.retry
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'retry'`.

Comment: Sorry, I have a stupid typo: `retry_url = request.url`

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** This solution is a workaround to the described problem, when facing a problem with infinite loops in request is always advisable to identify the cause instead of changing how the filter works.

- Create `customdupefilter.py` at the same level of you `middlewares.py` or `settings.py`.

  ```
  import os

  from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter

  class CustomDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
      default_max_retries = 5

      def __init__(self, path=None, debug=False):
          super().__init__(path, debug)
          self.request_counter = {}

      def request_seen(self, request):
          max_retries = request.meta.get('max_retries') or self.default_max_retries
          fp = self.request_fingerprint(request)
          if fp in self.fingerprints:
              if self.request_counter.get(fp) >= max_retries:
                  self.logger.info('Requests to %s exceeded maximum retries.', request)
                  return True
              else:
                  self.request_counter[fp] += 1
                  return None
          self.fingerprints.add(fp)
          self.request_counter.update({fp: 1})
          if self.file:
              self.file.write(fp + os.linesep)
  ```

*This assumes you are using a standard folder structure of a scrapy project, if you change the folder structure or the file name just be sure to change the reference in the settings as well.*

- Add the following line in your `settings.py`

  ```
  DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.customdupefilter.CustomDupeFilter'
  ```
- If you use `dont_filter=True` in the request **it will bypass this filter** just like the standard class.
- You can send in the request meta the `max_retries` param to change the number of maximum retries allowed for that particular request, if you don't it will use `default_max_retries`. Just in case a particular request needs more requests than most of the others. Example:

  ```
  yield Request(url=request_url, meta={'max_retries': 3})
  ```

### Explanation:

This will simple overwrite the standard filter class `RFPDupeFilter` and implements a counter to see how many times that same request is allowed to be repeated, once the maximum number is passed it will filter just like before.

As mentioned, `dont_filter` will bypass this filtering method.

Comment: When you suggest to create `customdupefilter.py` at the same level of `middlewares.py` or `settings.py`, ain't ***[this](https://imgur.com/DdbEbpt)*** what you meant? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, for a standard scrapy project strucure. You can put it somewhere else if you rather, just remember to update the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` in the `settings.py` so scrapy can import it.

Comment: As scrapy by default filters duplicate requests when `dont_filter=True` is not in place, will it make duplicate calls if I use `meta={'max_retry_times':5}` even when `dont_filter=True` is not there @renatodvc? Thanks.

Comment: If you use `dont_filter=True` the request skips the filter completely, if don't use it then the request will pass through the filter. The filter will only block requests made after it has been above the number of `max_retries` of that same request. **Notice the meta param is NOT `max_retry_times`.**  And Yes, if you duplicate a request, scrapy will execute both of them (*if under `max_retries`*), after all that was the point. The filter won't cause any duplicates, it will just allow them to happen (to a limit) if you yield duplicated requests.